# laravel php artisan produces error Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator

Tags: php, laravel

I have download the laravel files from the server and tried to recreate in the local host as I updated a page information in I need it back and its available in the back up

I downloaded and unzipped the files, put it in the project folder and ran

php artisan serv and it threw the below error

```
 In UrlGenerator.php line 120:
    
      Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in C:\Users\Dark\kpcc1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServ   
      iceProvider.php on line 65
```

I am a fresher and my developer is not available at the movement to help, so any help is appreciated I need that old page back.

i have read a few articles that say "Please make sure that you are not using any url() or asset() or other helpers functions inside your configuration files" but I don't know where and what these files are. These files were used to host the current website.

Comment: could be a few things, did you try `composer install` from the command line?

Comment: yes i did, i gave the following error  

``
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In UrlGenerator.php line 120:

  Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in C:\Users\Dark\kpcc1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServ   
  iceProvider.php on line 65


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1``

Comment: This error is also caused when you use either `asset()`, `url()` or `route()` method inside a config file. See more details in this [github forum](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32167).

Comment: Moreover, it is not possible to use dynamic methods inside a config file: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671